# Github на Android Studio выдает ошибку "Some files contain problems .."

Tags: java, android, github

Нажимаю на commit выдает ошибку

> Some files contain problems.
>   No errors and 8 warnings found.
>   Would you like to review them?

Что ему надо?

Comment: Хочет, что бы вы проверили проверили коммит или закоммитили содержимое :) Жумаю надо жать commit

Comment: я жму комит а он мне опять сообщение то что сверху. Окно Code analysinc.

Помогает лишь Perfomance disable analysinc. Тобишь отключение проверки анализа кода. Но ведь это не правильное решение. 

Чем чревовато это действие?

Comment: Про андроид студию сказать ничего не могу. Но предполагаю, что работает так же как и phpstorm. Там есть свой анализатор кода который выдаёт кучу ошибок и предупреждений. Но они как правило не правильно проанализированы.  Вы же перед тем как сделать релиз компилируете приложение и проверяете работоспособность. Поэтому я считаю Вам нечего беспокоится.